# WordPress Shortcode display Page title & exclude specific words form the Title

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a WordPress Shortcode that displays the page title, but I need now to exclude specific words form the Page Title

For example, sometimes I have in the title words like **Best or Top**

For example, if the page title is **Best City in California**
shortcode needs to show ( **City in California** )

This is my code on how to display the title

```
function post_title_shortcode(){
    return get_the_title();
}
add_shortcode('page_title','post_title_shortcode');
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems easy. Inside the function post_title_shortcode do something similar:

```
function post_title_shortcode() {
    $replacement = [
        'Bay' => '',
        // add as many as you want
    ];

    return str_replace(
        array_keys($replacement),
        array_values($replacement),
        get_the_title()
    );
}
```

Comment: this code doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: right, my bad. There was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Write some code in your shortcode handler to adjust the text of the title. This kind of thing might work.

```php
function post_title_shortcode(){
    $title = get_the_title();
    $title = trim( str_replace( 'Best ', '', $title, 1 ) );
    $title = trim( str_replace( 'Top ', '', $title, 1 ) );
    return $title;
}
add_shortcode('page_title','post_title_shortcode');
```

Comment: i get this error  = syntax error, unexpected '$title' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: Ooops, I wrote `$return` instead of `return`. Fixed.

Comment: now i get this error   = Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 18 of file wp-content/themes/site/functions.php. Please fix and try saving again.

Only variables can be passed by reference

Comment: any ideas how to make your code work?  looks like something is not correct here $title = trim( str_replace( 'Best ', '', $title, 1 ) );